# Laravel print role of user in table

Tags: laravel-5

I have a Laravel application. I'm using [this](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) package for roles and permissions. It works great.

I would now like to display a table of all users with their roles. Currently I'm solving it through the definition of the following in my UsersController.

```
 public function listUsers()
    {
        $users_admin = Role::where('name', 'admin')->first()->users()->get();
        $users_buyers = Role::where('name', 'buyer')->first()->users()->get();
        $users_sellers = Role::where('name', 'seller')->first()->users()->get();

        return view('admin.users.index', [
            'users_admin' => $users_admin,
            'users_buyers' => $users_buyers,
            'users_sellers' => $users_sellers
            ]);
    }
```

In the view, I then have 3 separate loops to display 3 tables (for admin users, buyers and sellers).

Needless to say I don't really like this approach and I would ideally have a single table displaying the users with their role.

So the idea is that I can write the following code (or similar) in the UsersController:

```
 $users = User::all();
```

while my view contains a single foreach stating the following:

```
@foreach( $users_sellers as $user )
  <tr>
    <td align="center" class="hidden-xs">{{ $user->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->displayRole($user->id) }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

In the above pseudocode, I have defined a helper that retrieves the role based on the user-id. Problem is I can't figure out what to put in the helper function?

Note: if there are other (better) methods than a helper, that would work as well for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see this package adds a relation in your *User* model, so `$user->roles` should be a collection with the roles assigned to the current user. To not make a query for each user you should eager load the users with their roles, like this: `$users = User::with('roles')->get();`.

Comment: I tried this indeed as well but I always get "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()"

Comment: Try with get: `$users = User::with('roles')->get();`.

Comment: This works. In the view, I'm doing the following: $user->roles[0]->name to print out the role name. This works. But what if there are multiple roles? Should I then just iterate over them or it there a better way to display all roles?

Comment: @wiwa1978 yes, you should iterate them, because there can be more than one.

Answer (score 0):

In your **Controller**, get the Role, if you have it in your table

```
public function listUsers()
    {
        $users_admin = Role::where('name', 'admin')->first()->users()->get();
        $users_buyers = Role::where('name', 'buyer')->first()->users()->get();
        $users_sellers = Role::where('name', 'seller')->first()->users()->get();
        $role = Role::get();

        return view('admin.users.index', [
            'users_admin' => $users_admin,
            'users_buyers' => $users_buyers,
            'users_sellers' => $users_sellers
            'role' => $role
            ]);
    }
```

In your **view**, just print the Role's name like this

```
@foreach( $users_sellers as $user )
  <tr>
    <td align="center" class="hidden-xs">{{ $user->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
    <td>{{ $role['$user->id']['role_name']</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

**Note :**

`<td>{{ $role['$user->id']['role_name']</td>`

This line depends on how you send the `$role` from controller to your view. It's purpose is to return the name of the role's id's array

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried this but it still uses the 3 collections, users_admin, users_buyers and users_sellers which I don't really like.